what is the meaning of $F(S)[X]?$
Source: Page no :$3$
Theorem $1$:
Let $E/F$ be a transcendental extension with transcendence basis $S$. Then $E$ is algebraic over $F(S).$
Proof:Let $a\in E$ be arbitrary. If $a \in S$, then $a$ is a root of the polynomial $f(X) = X − a \in F(S)[X]$; hence is algebraic over $F(S).$
My confusion:what is the  meaning of $F(S)[X]?$
My thinking: $F(S)[X]= F(S,X)$
If $a$ is  algebraic  over $F(S)$ ,there  are $x_{n-1},...,x_0 \in F(S) $ so that  $a^n+ x_{n-1}a^{n-1}+...+x_1 a+x_0=0$

If $k$ is any field, then $k[X]$ often stands for the ring of polynomials in the indeterminate  $X$ and coefficients in  $k$. Here $k=F(S)$, and the usual interpretation seems to fit the given context.
